# hazelcast-client.xml is not getting loaded hazelcast version 5.1.1

Tags: version, hazelcast

I am working on upgrade of Hazelcast version 5.1.1  when i am executing , in SPringboot project its say hazelcast-client exception while connecting to hazelcast java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not load hazelcast-client.xml

Answer (score 0):

If your code is something like

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new XmlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast-client.xml").build();
```

then it's probably just a problem with classpath. Logs will be no use, it's more likely a project structure issue.

Is the file in `src/main/resources` ?